# use dataframe column to change levels of factor

Tags: r, dplyr

how can I use a column of a data frame to change the levels of a factor ?

the example bellow is a simplification of the original dataset but shows what I am trying to accomplish.

The dataset structure

```
df <- data.frame(X=c("DFV","TUG","WQD","PRF","NJK"),Y=c(2000,5000,3000,1000,4000))
```

Arrange the order of X based on Y

```
ndf <- df %>% arrange(desc(Y))
```

Use the ndf$X to change the order of df$X (the original dataset).

```
df <- df %>% mutate(X = factor(X,levels=ndf$X))

desired result
df
    X    Y
1 TUG 5000
2 NJK 4000
3 WQD 3000
4 DFV 2000
5 PRF 1000
```

Please note that the problem is not to arrange the df in decreasing order, but how to use the ndf X column on the levels parameter. This is problem I am trying to figure out. Tks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach is correct but since you want to order the rows use it in `arrange` :

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% arrange(factor(X, levels = ndf$X))

#    X    Y
#1 TUG 5000
#2 NJK 4000
#3 WQD 3000
#4 DFV 2000
#5 PRF 1000
```

You can also use `match` :

```
df %>% arrange(match(X, ndf$X))
```

Comment: Hi, the answer didn't solve my problem but you confirmed that I am on the right track.

Comment: Why exactly it didn't solve your problem? It gives the expected output you have shown.

Comment: you are right. The output is correct. The original problem needed a little more, but I can consider your answer correct based on the example.

Answer (score 1):

There are two independent tasks: i) set levels of `X` based on `Y`; ii) reorder rows of `df`. Your question says about changing levels but your "desired output" seems to be about reordering the dataset. Please clarify if you need first, second, or both.

Changing levels, using `data.table`:

```
require(data.table)
setDT(df)
df[,X:=factor(X, levels=X[order(-Y)])]
```

(Note that it won't work if you have any duplicated values of `X`.)

Comment: Hi, your comment about duplicated values of X was useful. I didn't think about it.

Answer (score 0):

In the end the solution needed was:

`df %>% arrange(factor(X, levels = unique(ndf$X)))`